# Mounting local folder to windows container using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are lots of post on this topic but either they are discussing about `docker run`  or linux or discussing about earlier version of docker/ docker compose. I am simply trying to share a config file that resides locally, with my container. The following is my docker compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:  
  TestService:
    image: testservicelogmon
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - C:\ProgramData\Solution Name\Project Name:C:\ProgramData\Solution Name\Project Name:RW
```

**Note**: "Solution Name" and "Project Name" have space between them, and my config file resides in Project name folder.

The images gets created successfully but I always have `"Mounts": []` and `"Volumes": null`.
I went through the documentation and some posts at SO but couldn't find anything that would solve this problem for me. Below are couple of links I referred to. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks !

**Update**: It's just not with this folder, it seems like I am not able to mount any folder, whereas if I do a `docker run`like below it works perfectly fine.

```
docker run -it -v 'C:\ProgramData\Solution Name\Project Name:C:\ProgramData\C:\ProgramData\Solution Name\Project Name:RW' testservicelogmon:latest powershell
```

[docker named volume with targeting windows local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266647/docker-named-volume-with-targeting-windows-local-folder)

[volume binding using docker compose on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334021/volume-binding-using-docker-compose-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine. I was making a stupid mistake of running the `docker-compose build` command followed by `docker run`. This way everything was working fine but the mounts would always show empty. All I had to do was run `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up` and the mounts were populated as expected.